# Palavra reservada como nome de variável

Tags: java, json, gson

Estou construindo um programa que faz a integração de uma loja online com outro programa que controla o estoque físico de uma loja. A comunicação é feita através de requisições HTTP que respondem em formato JSON.

Em um dos JSON de resposta, tenho uma variável com nome: default. Sei que é uma palavra reservada na linguagem Java e que não posso utilizá-la como nome de uma variável, porém preciso consumir este JSON e transformá-lo em um objeto.

Estou usando a biblioteca Gson para me auxiliar a fazer esta "transformação". Mas não é possível fazer sem resolver o problema do nome da variável, e é sobre isso que quero ajuda. Tem como criar um "apelido" para a variável default para que o Gson consiga consumí-la? Ou existe outra solução melhor?

JSON

```
[{
“warehouses”: [
{
“id”: 1,
“createdAt”: “2016-12-27T10:58:13-02:00”,
“updatedAt”: “2016-12-27T14:57:39-02:00”,
“erpId”: “Armazém 1”,
“name”: “Armazém Revenda”,
“priority”: 1,
“branch”: {
“id”: 1,
“erpId”: “Filial 1”,
“name”: “Filial 1”,
“documentId”: “”,
“createdAt”: “2016-12-27T10:58:13-02:00”,
“updatedAt”: “2016-12-27T10:58:13-02:00”
},
“default”: true,
“quantity”: 1
}
]
}]
```

Warehouses

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Warehouses {

    private int id;
    private Date createdAt;
    private Date updateAt;
    private String erpId;
    private String name;
    private int priority;
    private Branch branch;
    private boolean default;
    private int quantity;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }
    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }
    public Date getUpdateAt() {
        return updateAt;
    }
    public void setUpdateAt(Date updateAt) {
        this.updateAt = updateAt;
    }
    public String getErpId() {
        return erpId;
    }
    public void setErpId(String erpId) {
        this.erpId = erpId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }
    public void setPriority(int priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }
    public Branch getBranch() {
        return branch;
    }
    public void setBranch(Branch branch) {
        this.branch = branch;
    }
    public boolean isDefault() {
        return default;
    }
    public void setDefault(boolean default) {
        this.default = default;
    }
    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

}
```

Branch

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Branch {

    private int id;
    private String erpId;
    private String name;
    private String documentId;
    private Date createdAt;
    private Date updateAt;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getErpId() {
        return erpId;
    }
    public void setErpId(String erpId) {
        this.erpId = erpId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDocumentId() {
        return documentId;
    }
    public void setDocumentId(String documentId) {
        this.documentId = documentId;
    }
    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }
    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }
    public Date getUpdateAt() {
        return updateAt;
    }
    public void setUpdateAt(Date updateAt) {
        this.updateAt = updateAt;
    }

}
```

Consumindo JSON

```
public static List<Warehouses> JSONtoList(String strJson) {
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<Warehouses>>() {
    }.getType();

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").create();
    List<Warehouses> lista = gson.fromJson(strJson, type);

    return lista;
}
```

Chamando e Executando (Sim, a string é passada por requisição HTTP, este é apenas um exemplo para ilustrar como estou fazendo)

```
String strJson = "[{\r\n" + 
        "“warehouses”: [\r\n" + 
        "{\r\n" + 
        "“id”: 1,\r\n" + 
        "“createdAt”: “2016-12-27T10:58:13-02:00”,\r\n" + 
        "“updatedAt”: “2016-12-27T14:57:39-02:00”,\r\n" + 
        "“erpId”: “Armazém 1”,\r\n" + 
        "“name”: “Armazém Revenda”,\r\n" + 
        "“priority”: 1,\r\n" + 
        "“branch”: {\r\n" + 
        "“id”: 1,\r\n" + 
        "“erpId”: “Filial 1”,\r\n" + 
        "“name”: “Filial 1”,\r\n" + 
        "“documentId”: “”,\r\n" + 
        "“createdAt”: “2016-12-27T10:58:13-02:00”,\r\n" + 
        "“updatedAt”: “2016-12-27T10:58:13-02:00”\r\n" + 
        "},\r\n" + 
        "“default”: true,\r\n" + 
        "“quantity”: 1\r\n" + 
        "}\r\n" + 
        "]\r\n" + 
        "}]";

List<Warehouses> lista = JSONUtils.JSONtoList(strJson);

for(Warehouses w: lista) {
    System.out.println(w.getId());
    System.out.println(w.isDefault());
}
```

Erro

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke public model.Warehouses() with no args
    at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$3.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:118)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:212)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841)
    at util.JSONUtils.JSONtoList(JSONUtils.java:168)
    at view.PrincipalView.<init>(PrincipalView.java:69)
    at view.LoginView$1.actionPerformed(LoginView.java:35)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Syntax error on token "default", invalid VariableDeclarator
    This method must return a result of type boolean
    Syntax error on token "default", delete this token
    Syntax error on token "default", invalid VariableDeclaratorId
    Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Assignment
    Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody

    at model.Warehouses.<init>(Warehouses.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$3.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:110)
    ... 46 more
```

Comment: Explique melhor o contexto. Qual é o código Java que você está usando para decodificar esse JSON? Está dando algum erro? Qual?

Comment: @bfavaretto O código é irrelevante, ele funciona com qualquer outro JSON que uso para transformar em objeto. O problema é exatamente o que eu disse: no JSON em questão, tem um nome de variável (default) que é palavra reservada na linguagem Java e eu não sei como contornar esta situação.

Comment: O problema é que a decodificação desse JSON está tentando usar a palavra reservada num contexto onde ela não é permitida. Por isso precisamos saber como você está fazendo isso. E se dá alguma mensagem de erro. E qual erro.

Comment: @bfavaretto Adicionei parte dos códigos do projeto e o log de erros que apresenta quando executo. Veja se fica um pouco mais claro. Obrigado.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6258849/825789

Comment: @lys já tentou a solução do link do acima? Me parece plausivel.

Comment: @ArticunoL Tentei a solução e apresentou um novo erro. Alterei a pergunta para um exemplo simples e executável para que possa ver o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Pra mim voce alterou completamente a duvida inicial, q era sobre usar palavra reservada. REcomendo que nao faça isso pois voce desqualificou completamente a resposta do colega abaixo. Se gerou um novo problema, faça uma nova pergunta.

Comment: @ArticunoL Mas o nome da variável no JSON é default. Porque usaria outro apelido?

Comment: @ArticunoL Certo. Vou voltar a pergunta para o estado que a resposta seja aceitável.

Comment: Ja fiz isso, a solucao do problema de usar palavras reservadas foi resolvido, tanto q o erro parou de ocorrer nao e mesmo? Agora é outro problema completamente diferente

Comment: @ArticunoL Você está certo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer algo como:

```
package com.javacreed.examples.gson.part1;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Box {

  @SerializedName("w")
  private int width;

  @SerializedName("h")
  private int height;

  @SerializedName("d")
  private int depth;

  // Methods removed for brevity
}
```

Utilizando a anotação `@SerializedName` para fazer com que o nome do atributo no seu objeto java seja reconhecido por outro no seu JSON.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta. Foi bastante útil.